# I didn't get library async for node.js, where i'm wrong?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I tried a lot to use aync library in nodejs but my simpliest test even don't works.

```
var async = require('async');

var i = 0 ;

var inc = function(){
    i++;
} ;

var show = function(){
    console.log(i) ;
} ;

var err = function(err){
    console.log(err) ;
} ;

async.forever(inc,err) ;
async.forever(show,err) ;
```

Function don't loop at all and the output is only

```
1
```

What i'm doint wrong please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`async.forever()` passes a `callback` to `show` and `inc` that they need to call:

```
var inc = function(done){
    i++;
    setImmediate(done);
};

var show = function (done) {
    console.log(i);
    setImmediate(done);
};
```

Using [`setImmediate`](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg) (or [`setTimeout`](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg)) makes the call asynchronous so you don't get a stack overflow error:

```
var inc = function(done){
    i++;
    done();
};
```

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

var inc = function(done){
                  ^
```

And, keep in mind that the `async` library doesn't make tasks asynchronous; it assumes the tasks are already asynchronous and simply helps manage them. Using synchronous tasks with `async` will still block in most cases.